# Prefabs not visible in unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene, prefab

I bought an asset from unity store and installed XR interaction toolkit therein. Everything works fine. When I drag prefabs from another asset into the scene and deploy it into oculus quest 2, these prefabs become invisible.

I have tried giving these prefabs the same properties as that of the visible objects in the scene but nothing is working for me. does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I also created a game object (cube) but it's not also visible when I deployed it. This suggests that the problem is not the prefabs that I'm trying to add to the scene

Comment: What do you mean by "drag prefabs from another asset into the scene"?

Comment: So there are two assets. I want to use the scene from the first asset. I only need an object from the second asset, not the entire scene. I just simply imported these two assets, open the scene I need in the first asset, then drag the prefab of the object I need in the second asset into the scene of the first asset. This is something I usually do and it works. Just don't know what went wrong this time.

Comment: I later figured it out. I made the prefab a child of the main camera under XR Origin, I deployed it and the prefab became visible but moved with the camera. I then removed this prefab as the child of the main camera and just placed it back in the hierarchy and everything worked fine. I do not see anything technical here but somehow it worked for me